# Unable to install MySQL as a service with name alfrescoMySQL

Tags: alfresco

When i install alfresco to my system "unable to install MySQL as a service with name alfrescoMySQL " Error will apprear.

Comment: Do you have a previous copy of Alfresco on your system that you didn't uninstall properly first? Any other error details?

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: By the way, consider using Linux instead... it will make you life much easier.